# Show attached images inside popup with ArcGIS Online?

Tags: arcgis-online

In ArcGIS Online popups how does one display attached images inline as an image instead of just a link? In case of multiple images I'm okay with just first one showing inline.

Under "Configure Popup" checking " Show feature attachments as links" results in text-only links.  If the "Pop-up Media" control is used to add an image, it shows inline, however one has to know the URL ahead of time. The drop down selector does not show attachments as a possibility.

[image: Showing attached images as text only links]

[image: Attachment attribute not listed]

#### Desired result

Popup showing 1st image inline, hidden beneath fold are rest of attachments as links.

[image: popup showing 1st image inline]

Comment: best idea for this: *thumbnails* (Esri probably needs to do it their side), courtesy of http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2012/04/26/tips-for-displaying-photos-in-pop-ups/#comment-3801

Comment: perhaps this will be helpful. http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2012/07/03/add-flickr-photos-to-arcgis-online-web-maps/

Comment: Vote for this feature on [Ideas.arcgis.com](http://ideas.arcgis.com/ideaView?id=087E00000005FcyIAE#sthash.JbcOvCrg)

Answer (score 4):

Going through the same difficulty, I found a semi-automated solution that works as following:

1. The popup is opened and the attachment urls load and appear as links.
2. A placeholder image (an arrow in my case) is loaded where the image will soon load.
3. Clicking the placeholder retrieves the url from the attachment link and replaces its own source url with the retrieved url, making the attachment image show.

To make it work, put the following values in the popup image configuration:

- URL: `data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAkAAAAHCAIAAABV+fA3AAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAADJJREFUeNpi+I8KFi1aBGczMWCAxYsXQxhY5ODS2OUg0jjlYmNjmXBJYDcTIgEEAAEGAGysItsbwoS/AAAAAElFTkSuQmCC`
   (this is just an inline image of an arrow: 
  you can replace it with any other url.
- Link: `javascript:void(document.getElementsByClassName("esriViewPopup")[0].getElementsByTagName("img")[0].src = document.getElementsByClassName("esriViewPopup")[0].getElementsByTagName("a")[0].href);`
  this makes the link run a javascript code that makes the (first) attachment link become the image's URL.

Hope this helps.

Comment: how can I do this without a dev edition web app.

Comment: Great idea but possibly something has changed since 2016 -- I get "BLOCKED" messages.

Answer (score 4):

Another alternative is to use the new Operations Dashboard and add your web map to it.  Pop-ups in the dashboard map will display all the images attached to a feature by default like in the image below:

[image]

Comment: THANKS -- I made an Operations Dashboard in ArcGIS Online but keep my data in ArcGIS Enterprise. I don't have to manage more storage online and allows me to make the AGOL app open to the public so I don't have to maintain separate user accounts; Users are prompted to use their AGE accounts to get the feature layer to load.

Comment: Not sure if it would make sense to mark this as the answer but it is the best workaround.

Answer (score 2):

I guess a potential workaround that would add a couple steps to your workflow would be the following:

1. Add text field [ATTACH_URL] (255 char) to the attribute table of the feature layer
2. Create a new point and upload the attachment
3. Click on the popup, then right-click and ‘Copy link address’ from the link to the attachment
4. Edit the feature, and paste this URL into the [ATTACH_URL] field
   [image]
5. Configure the popup, and under Pop-up Media, click ADD>Image
6. Configure the popup as the following:
   [image]

You would then have to repeat steps 3-4 every time you publish a new feature.

Not ideal or automated, but possible.

Comment: thanks for a workaround. Like you say, not ideal but possible. There's got to be a way to get at the system attribute. ...Closest geonet thread: https://geonet.esri.com/message/544252#544252 (also unanswered)

Comment: You can automate most of this via attribute expressions, save for retrieving the attachment info, which has to be a field calculate. At least it's only 1 quick manual step when features are added, which could be further automated via an attribute rule.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a helpful GP tool that will add attachments to a pop-up:

https://geonet.esri.com/docs/DOC-7445

Comment: Please, don't post a link-only answer. Links can be lost in a future. You can add steps or highlights in your answer

Comment: Hi Jake, please take a look [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/promotion)

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is to use the "Pop-up Media" option under the "configure Pop-up" dialog within ArcGIS online for the layer you want to work with.

For the URL config you want to substitute 2 parts of the URL with `{OBJECTID}` like this bellow :

```
https://your.portal.url/server/rest/services/service_folder/service_name/MapServer/0/{OBJECTID}/attachments/{OBJECTID}?
```

This should give you the nice clean output you are expecting.

Comment: If you try this, I suggest using a different field, objectIDs are notoriously unstable.

Comment: I think you'd need to set up a field, I tested it with OBJECTID and it does not work for me in AGOL or AGE or WABDE..

Comment: The last segment is the **ATTACHMENT** ID, not the **OBJECT** ID e.g. if you had 2 attachments per feature, the urls for feature 3's attachments would be ../MapServer/0/3/attachments/5 and /6 
You have to retrieve the attachment ID using arcade: Attachments($feature) in a field calculate or attribute rule (not supported in attribute expressions currently).

Comment: @JMers it is best to avoid using OBJECTID as a unique identifier for features in analysis due to edits potentially reordering features and subsequently OBJECTID, but the feature ID segment of the above URL must match the index of the feature in the layer, which OBJECTID inherently represents.

Answer (score 0):

If your layer is hosted in AGOL, you can now use the map viewer beta and select the gallery option for attachments under configure pop-up.

This option is currently disabled for enterprise/portal hosted layers. An ideal workaround is to create a web app with the attachment viewer template.

If you're on an older version of enterprise (as we are) there is a bug where an attachment viewer app doesn't honour image orientation. The workaround I've developed, which may be useful to others in similar circumstance, is:

Calculate a field (using arcade) including comma-separated attachment IDs:

```
//calculate the attach IDs field
function IDs(f){
    return f.ID;
}

var Attach_ = Attachments($feature);
var AttachIDs = Map(Attach_, IDs);
return Concatenate(AttachIDs,',');
```

This must be a field CALCULATE as attribute expressions do not currently support the Attachments function. I believe an attribute rule may also work.

Once the above is available, you can add attribute expressions in your pop-up (1 per attached image) as:

```
//build the URL for image attachment <ImageNumber>
var ImageNumber = 0
var AttachIDs = split($feature.AttachmentIDs,',')

if(ImageNumber > count(AttachIDs) - 1)
    return ''

var AttachID = AttachIDs[ImageNumber]
var BaseURL = "<your_domain>/server/rest/services/Hosted/LayerName/FeatureServer/0/"
var ObjectID = $feature.OBJECTID
return BaseURL + ObjectID + "/attachments/" + AttachID
```

ImageNumber must be incremented for each expression, starting from 0.

After that you can add an image per attachment as pop-up media, referencing the matching attribute expression for the url and link fields.